# Openwebkitsharp - COMException was unhandled?

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, webview, open-webkit-sharp

I am making a c# app that get a website I have and views it in the app. For this I am using OpenWebKitSharp to get the web view with HTML5. I followed all the instructions in the How-to-use.txt but, it runs with a popup saying it is not initialized and I should follow the How-to-use.txt. I am open to alternative as long as they can use HTML5.

My System:

- Windows 10
- Latest Visual Studio
- Latest OpenWebKitSharp

---

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WebKit;

namespace Cosmic_Stocks
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webKitBrowser1.UseJavaScript = true;

            Uri myUri = new Uri("http://cosmicsearch.org/stocks", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            webKitBrowser1.Url = myUri;
        }
    }
}
```

The Popup:

[image: The Popup]
Update:

Now there is a new error.

```
COMException was unhandled
AN unhandled exception of type 'system.runtime.interop.services.comexception' occored inopenwebkitsharp.dll
```

I got that when I was redoing the program

Comment: Do you guys need more info to answer the question?

Comment: Could you post at least the code you already have? But my wild guess (without seeing your code) is that your missing a `new OpenWebKitSharp()` or something like that

Comment: That is it plus the `WebKitBrowser.url = ...`

Comment: Than edit your question and insert the real piece of code. Without the actual code, nobody can / will help...

Comment: added code to question

Comment: added the error popup pic

Comment: Tried to fix it again still not working!

Comment: Did you copy everything from the core folder inside the right build folder?

Comment: I am still having this problem any solutions once I get 75 reputation I will add a bounty

Comment: Well, if you could provide a download link to the openwebkitsharp, i could take a look at it...

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/open-webkit-sharp/

Comment: Alright, maybe it's got to do something with the fact that the [Form.Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx) function `Occurs before a form is displayed for the first time.` So my suggestion is to move everything off the method and put it in your Form constructor right after `InitializeComponent();`. But I'm not sure if that will work...

Comment: Hmm... Maybe I will try that thank you I just do not have the computer with the code right now

Comment: Good luck. My guess is that because of that the screen isn't initialized, the Webkit browser isn't initializedalso. So I really hope for you that this is the problem.

Comment: Testing that code right now it took me a long time too get time to test it

Comment: Tried it did not work

Comment: Could you upload a zip of your project?

Comment: Following instructions worked for me. Let me know if you have questions or need any additional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following ***How to use.txt*** instructions worked just fine:

[image]

Notes:

- Windows 10
- VisualStudio 2015 Community Edition
- .NET 4.5.2
- OpenWebKitSharp 3.0.1.0023

When adding project **References** to **OpenWebKitSharp.dll** and **WebKit.Interop.dll**, both files were selected from the **open-webkit-sharp\Binary** folder.

The same **OpenWebKitSharp.dll** from the **open-webkit-sharp\Binary** folder was added to **Tools -> Choose Toolbox Items...**

All files and sub-folders under **open-webkit-sharp\Core** and **open-webkit-sharp\References** were copied under **bin\Debug** folder of the target project.

The very same code as in your post was used:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webKitBrowser1.UseJavaScript = true;

        Uri myUri = new Uri("http://cosmicsearch.org/stocks", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        webKitBrowser1.Url = myUri;
    }
}
```